# cannot get folder created by another apps script on google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Using the following apps script function i can successfully create folders in google drive:

```
function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email) {  

    var parentFolderId = "FOLDER_ID";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
    var subfolder;

        try {
    subfolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName([name, email].join(" ")).next();
    }
    catch(e) {
    subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder([name, email].join(" "));
    }
      var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
        file = subfolder.createFile(blob);

          file = subfolder.createFile(file, data);
   Logger.log(subfolder);  
      return "OK";
}
```

i want to access the folder using the following script:

```
function downloadFile(e) {  
  var parentFolderId = "FOLDER_ID";
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);

 var subfolderId;
 var subfolders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName([name, email].join(" "));

while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = subfolders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getId());
}
}
```

appsscript.json for uploadFileToGoogleDrive:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Bucharest",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

appsscript.json for downloadFile :

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Bucharest",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

The script can access **ONLY** the folders Created with google drive Web!
But cannot get the folders created with other apps script.

Note that the two functions (upload and download) are in separate google apps scripts.

Comment: The question will be better if 1.Permissions/scopes granted to the each script are  provided. 2.  The exact error message is quoted instead of any  subjective inference of the error

Comment: Thanks TheMaster  agian for your help, the permission (```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly``` and ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive``` 
  are granted for the second script, but when i grant the first it stops working. 2. there is no error, the script keeps waiting for logs

Comment: Could  you [edit] those details into your question? 2. It should be logged in view>stackdriver logs.

Comment: In stackdriver logs: No logs are available for this execution.

Comment: You need to clear the filter at the top. Are you visiting view>stackdriver logging? Don't go to view> executions>logs. 3. Also it might take some time before the uploaded files show up. Try adding `Logger.log(subfolders.hasNext())` before calling it in `while`

Comment: You said "The two functions are in separate google app script", but are they under the same Gmail account?

Comment: yes they are under same account, is it necessary for the upload script to be granted with ```oauthScopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive``` ?

Comment: @TheMaster when i add your suggested logger before "while" , the logger returns False

Comment: `name` and `email` might not match, If you weren't able to get the folder even 30 minutes after the upload/ creation.

Comment: i cannot get the folder even after 2 days of testing.. i checked the name and email with the same name criteria for another folder created from the drive web and the script worked. thanks for any help pal.

Comment: All I can say is that the issue is not *script can access ONLY the folders Created with google drive*. Something else might be amiss. Try looking for other issues. If you're sure that's issue, One last thing to try: Downgrade both projects from V8 to DEPRECATED_ES5. If that  doesn't help, create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: i just try to set the permission to EDIT using the following ```folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
``` in the upload script, then the folder become accessible to the other script. SO should the sharing permission be EDIT to be visible! i want to keep it VIEW only

Comment: @user Is it the same account that deployed both the web apps? If it's the same account, you don't even need `VIEW` permission. Owner has full access always.

Comment: the problem is very strange, i found that it depends on the name! for example if the name of the folder is "user12m" the script works. and when the name "user11s" it doesn't work and the logger show "null" as result. can someone explain to me please?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working for me even with that "user11s" folder name. Are you really sure you have the right permissions to access the folder? For exmple: Maybe you are using two different users when running your scripts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alberto vielma, As @TheMaster suggested, my problem was in `name and email`, a hidden "space" was by mistake in their string values which prevent them to match the folder name. Thanks all..